# Split a number by 13 digits using php

Tags: php

I want to make a program which splits a long number into pieces of 13 digited number such that I can loop for every 13 digits just using php.

```
$number = 012345678901230123456789123
```

Should output

```
0123456789123
0123456789123
```

And it should be for any large number having the number of digit multiple of 13.It looks about looping and algorithm but I want to make it as short as possible and I have doubts on how to do it. So I am just asking about the main concept.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to simply divide by 13 power of 10 and grab first 13 integer. But it did not work for longer number

Comment: what about the digits that are left after spliting every 13 digits? in your case a `3` is left behind

Comment: voting to close as it is to broad asking about an algorithm and not a programming doubt. 

and it can be solved in many different ways, regex, loops, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most dynamic solution is probably to use array_functions on the string.
So str_split to make it array then chunk it in size 13 and implode the arrays.

```
$number = "012345678901230123456789123";
$arr = array_chunk(str_split($number), 13);
foreach($arr as &$val){
    $val = implode($val);
}
```

https://3v4l.org/LsNFt

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function where you can use your string and size as parameter and return an array of strings of the desired length:

```
function splitString($str, $packetSize) {
    $output = [];
    $size = strlen($str);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i += $packetSize) {
        if ($i + $packetSize < $size) {
            $output[]= substr($str, $i, $packetSize);
        } else {
            $output[]=substr($str, $i);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```